# Setup review targets for branches in git

Tags: git

I have created a branch locally using the command -

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

made it a remote branch using the command -

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

I am trying to set review targets for the branch using the command -

```
git reviewtargets <branch>
```

But I get a message saying - `'reviewtargets' is not a git command`.

How can I setup review targets for the branch I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Any git xxx command (which is not a native git feature) supposes the presence of an executable named `git-xxx` (no extension) anywhere in your `$PATH`.

Make sure that you have `git-reviewtargets` in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to set review targets for the branch using the command

What is this command? Its not a git command.
I assume you wish to see list of branches that you gave.

Do this:

- List branches
  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

  ```
  # List all branches locally and remotes
  git branch -a
  ```
- List remotes 
  https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

  ```
  git remote -vvv
  ```

To see a full list of git commands type `git` or `git --help`